# sky texture doesn't work in renders

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting

when I do my rendering on Blender 3.0 the sky texture doesn't show up, but we I observe my viewport screen I can see the effects.
My "transparent option" is unchecked, I use cycle and I tried to use both CPU and GPU rendering.
[image]
Thanks you and sorry for my english.

Comment: if Allens answer doesn't help, pls provide blend file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for objects like this in the *Outliner*.

[image]

This object is hidden in the viewport (Eye icon) but still active in render (Camera icon).  It looks like you have a hidden object blocking the window.